# Cannot add class to aspx.cs file

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have 2 files in my web site project,  Translator2.aspx and Translator2.aspx.cs. I want to add new class (Erwin:Translator2) to my Translator2.aspx.cs file. However it was error like this :

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error     'translator2_aspx' does not contain a definition for 'Switch'
>   and no extension method 'Switch' accepting a first argument of type
>   'translator2_aspx' could be found (are you missing a using directive
>   or an assembly reference?)
>   C:\Users\erwin.surya\Documents\Visual
>   Studio 2017\WebSites\WebSite1\Translator2.aspx    33

Here is my Translator2.aspx code:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" Async="true" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Translator2.aspx.cs" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master"   Inherits="Translator2" %>

<asp:Content runat="server" ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">


            <div class="form-group">
                    <asp:Label runat="server" AssociatedControlID="English" CssClass="col-md-2 control-label">English</asp:Label>
                    <div class="col-md-10">

                        <asp:TextBox  Height="79px" TextMode="MultiLine" Width="452px"  runat="server" ID="English" CssClass="form-control" />

                    </div>      </div>  



                    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                        <asp:Button runat="server" OnClick="Submit"  Height="39px" Width="100px" Text="Translate" CssClass="btn btn-default" />
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                        <asp:Button runat="server" OnClick="Switch" Height="39px" Width="100px" Text="Switch" CssClass="btn btn-default" />
                    </div>


<br /><br /><br />
           <div class="form-group">
                    <asp:Label runat="server" AssociatedControlID="Japanese" CssClass="col-md-2 control-label">Japanese</asp:Label>
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        <asp:TextBox Height="79px" TextMode="MultiLine" Width="452px"   runat="server" ID="Japanese" CssClass="form-control" />

                    </div></div> 
<br /><br />
            <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="ErrorMessage" Visible="false">
                    <p class="text-danger">
                        <asp:Literal runat="server" ID="FailureText" />
                    </p>
                </asp:PlaceHolder>
</asp:Content>
```

Here is my Translator2.aspx.cs code:

```
     partial class Translator2 : Page

{
    public async void Submit(object sender, EventArgs e)
{



    string key = "92fcf1387f844a8";
    var authTokenSource = new AzureAuthToken(key.Trim());
    string authToken;
    try
    {
        authToken = await authTokenSource.GetAccessTokenAsync();
    }

    catch (HttpRequestException)
    {
        if (authTokenSource.RequestStatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Request to token service is not authorized (401). Check that the Azure subscription key is valid.");
            return;
        }
        if (authTokenSource.RequestStatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Forbidden)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Request to token service is not authorized (403). For accounts in the free-tier, check that the account quota is not exceeded.");
            return;
        }
        throw;
    }


    string output = "";
    string text = English.Text;

    string uri = "https://api.microsofttranslator.com/v2/Http.svc/Translate?text=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(text) + "&from=" + "en" + "&to=" + "ja";
    HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
    httpWebRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization", authToken);
    using (WebResponse response = httpWebRequest.GetResponse())
    using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
    {
        DataContractSerializer dcs = new DataContractSerializer(Type.GetType("System.String"));
        string translation = (string)dcs.ReadObject(stream);
        Console.WriteLine("Translation for source text '{0}' from {1} to {2} is", text, "en", "ja");
        Console.WriteLine(translation);
        output = translation;
    }
    Japanese.Text = output;

}

class Erwin : Translator2
{
    string from, to;
    public void SwapStrings(string s1, string s2)

{

    string temp = s1;
    s1 = s2;
    s2 = temp;



    from = s1;
    to = s2;

    testing.Text = from;
    testing1.Text = to;

}

protected void Switch(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string str1 = testing.Text;
    string str2 = testing1.Text;
    System.Console.WriteLine("Inside Main, before swapping: {0} {1}", str1, str2);

    SwapStrings(str1, str2);
}

}
```

Do you have any idea why I can't add Erwin:Translato2 class? everything works fine before I add the class. Did I miss something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Switch` method is in a different class than the class that is powering your aspx page. If you want switch to be some kind of utility method, you should create a new class, maybe `Erwin` in a completely separate file (Erwin.cs), and have a `switch` method inside that that is public and probably static. I also note that `switch` doesn't return anything, so not sure what you are trying to accomplish with it.

The `OnClick` handler for your button should be in the code behind -- ie in the `Translator2` class. Inside this handler, you could call `Erwin.Switch()`.

Comment: Hi, can't I add this class to the current aspx.cs file? I thought we can create multiple classes in one aspx.cs file?

Comment: I want to use the from,to string from class Erwin, to be able to use it in class Translator

Comment: You *can* have this class in here, but you should ask why. If it's only used by this page, put it's functionality in the page. If it's used by other pages, it makes sense to be in a separate document. You will find that one .cs file per class makes sense.

Comment: you can do that, but you will have to make the class and the properties public.

Comment: Hi Jonathan, It's used in this page only (submit and switch button in the same page). So i need to make class and the properties public? do you have any document talking about this? I don't know how to do it. Please let me know if you have links which I can refer to.

I thought I have created Erwin : translator2 class?

Comment: Thank you!! I understand now!

Comment: However I still wonder, why can't I add new class into my aspx.cs file? what did I miss?